# Failing to uploud latex file to arXiv. ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Loss_Median.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, eps

This is my first question. I am using TeXstudio 2.11.0

I am trying to upload tex file to arXiv.

tried to use: `\pdfoutput=1` in the first line of the main file with no help.

I upload `Loss_Median.eps` but the error is about `Loss_Median.pdf`

This is the TeX log:

```
[verbose]: pdflatex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.out' (1480013583 >= 1480013582)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.aux' (1480013583 >= 1480013582)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && pdflatex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/courier.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathtools.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mhsetup.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex))
) (/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex))
) (/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex))) (./defs.tex)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/was/gensymb.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
No file Proxy_voting_Arxiv.aux.
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2011/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd)
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ptm.fd)
Overfull \hbox (0.99277pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 139--139
[][] 

LaTeX Warning: Citation `miller1969program' on page 1 undefined on input line 1
73.

(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pcr.fd)
Overfull \hbox (26.82027pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 176--176
[][]$\OT1/pcr/m/n/8 http : / / design-[]milk . com / comfy-[]app-[]$ $brings-[]
group-[]voting-[]workplace-[]thermostat$\OT1/ptm/m/n/8 .| 

LaTeX Warning: Citation `christian2005voting' on page 1 undefined on input line
178.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `jonsson2011user' on page 1 undefined on input line 178
.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `mueller1972representative' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 179.

[1{/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `riddick1985riddick' on page 2 undefined on input line 
183.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `petrik2009participation' on page 2 undefined on input 
line 183.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `tullock1967proportional' on page 2 undefined on input 
line 188.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:median' on page 2 undefined on input line 202.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:mean' on page 2 undefined on input line 202.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:binary' on page 2 undefined on input line 202.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:results' on page 2 undefined on input line 203.

[2]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:line' on page 3 undefined on input line 233.


Overfull \hbox (0.33281pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 233--234
\OT1/ptm/m/it/10 mech-a-nism\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 , $[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it
/10 S\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) = [] [][] \OML/cmm/m/it/10 s[]$\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 , and the
\OT1/ptm/m/it/10 Me-dian mech-a-nism\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 , $[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML
/cmm/m/it/10 S\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) = []\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 f\OML/cmm/m/it/10 s[] \OMS
/cmsy/m/n/10 2

LaTeX Warning: Citation `mueller1972representative' on page 3 undefined on inpu
t line 243.

[3]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:line' on page 4 undefined on input line 270.

(./line_fig.tex)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `elkind2015equilibria' on page 4 undefined on input lin
e 279.

[4]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:line' on page 5 undefined on input line 287.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `wackerly2007mathematical' on page 5 undefined on input
line 306.


Overfull \hbox (11.55136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 306--309
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 We note that the loss is the sum of two com-po-nents [[]]: th
e (squared) bias $\U/msb/m/n/10 E\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 [\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 g[]\OT1/cmr/
m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 ^^@

Overfull \hbox (19.96048pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 306--309
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 g\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )][]$ \OT1
/ptm/m/n/10 and the vari-ance $\U/msb/m/n/10 V\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 [\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10
g[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )]$\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 . A
mech-a-nism $\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 g$ \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 is \OT1/ptm/m/it/10 un-bi-ase
d \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 for $\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Q; f\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 if $\U/msb/m/n/10 E\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 [\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 g[]\OT1/c
mr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )] =

LaTeX Warning: Citation `moulin1980strategy' on page 5 undefined on input line 
351.


Overfull \hbox (29.53645pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 351--357
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 min-i-mizes the sum of dis-tances to all re-ported po-si-tions,
i.e. $[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 
2 [][] [][] j \OML/cmm/m/it/10 s[] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 ^^@
[5]
Overfull \hbox (12.12004pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 370--372
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Thus $[][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/1
0 )$ \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 al-ways re-turns the proxy clos-est to $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [](\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 , w
hereas $[][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$

LaTeX Warning: Citation `stigler1973studies' on page 6 undefined on input line 
383.


Overfull \hbox (18.23727pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 382--385
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Note that for sym-met-ric dis-tri-bu-tions, both of $[][]\OT1
/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) = [](\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\OT
1/cmr/m/n/10 )$ \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 and $[][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 S[]\
OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) =
[6]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma:median_optimal' on page 7 undefined on input li
ne 400.

[7]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:loss_m' on page 8 undefined on input line 492.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `conj:median' on page 8 undefined on input line 493.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Loss_Median.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.498 ...ludegraphics[scale=0.42]{Loss_Median.eps}
%images/
? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.498 ...ludegraphics[scale=0.42]{Loss_Median.eps}
%images/
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Proxy_voting_Arxiv.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.aux' (1480013583 >= 1480013583)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper]{article}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper]{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Proxy_voting_Arxiv.log.

[verbose]: tex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper]{article}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[letterpaper]{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Proxy_voting_Arxiv.log.

[verbose]: tex 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'Proxy_voting_Arxiv.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'defs.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'defs.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./defs.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \newtheorem
{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \newtheorem
{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
No pages of output.
Transcript written on defs.log.

[verbose]: tex 'defs.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'defs.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./defs.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \newtheorem
{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.3 \newtheorem
{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
No pages of output.
Transcript written on defs.log.

[verbose]: tex 'defs.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'defs.tex'
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'line_fig.tex'
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'line_fig.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./line_fig.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \begin
{center}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.27 \begin
{center}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on line_fig.log.

[verbose]: tex 'line_fig.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2011/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/1732234/ && tex 'line_fig.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
(./line_fig.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \begin
{center}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.27 \begin
{center}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on line_fig.log.

[verbose]: tex 'line_fig.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'line_fig.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: pdfLaTeX doesn't support `.eps` as an image format natively. Convert the image to `.pdf` first and include it without an extension (`\includegraphics[...]{Loss_Median}`). But there are other errors in your file too.

Comment: can you explain a bit what is pdfLaTeX?
does TeXstudio considered pdfLaTeX?
does every TEX writer that makes PDF is pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @AlanMunn, Converting the figures into .pdf solved the problem. 
Thanks!